# dont disconnect wifi when ethernet cable is plugged in

Tags: networking, wireless

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 and I have a problem.

When I plug in something the ethernet, wifi gets disabled, even if I don't use the ethernet port for the internet connection.

Is there a way to fix this ?  I often use a company wlan while I'm connected to a robot or PLC via LAN, so I need the wlan for Internet, Mail, etc., while I use the Ethernet Cable for Remote Coding...

Thank you!